# Admin Privileges in a controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to put an admin role privileges in my post method in controller.

Whatever login I use, the takes it as if everyone has an admin role. Any ideas on what needs to change so the code execute correctly in the if statement?

Thank you.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Autherize(Vidly2.Models.User userModel)
{
        using (LoginDataBaseEntities db = new LoginDataBaseEntities())
        {
            var userDetails = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == userModel.Email && x.Password == userModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            var admins = db.Users.Where(x => x.Role.Contains("Admin")).FirstOrDefault();

            if (userDetails == null)
            {
                userModel.LoginErrorMessage = "Wrong username or password.";
                return View("Index", userModel);
            }
            else {
                if (admins == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["userID"] = userDetails.Email;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Keys");
                }
            }
        }

        return View();
}
```

Comment: `db.Users.Where(x => x.Role.Contains("Admin")).FirstOrDefault()` will just return any user that has the Admin role. Maybe you should simply check if the user you've already queried has the Admin role: `userDetails.Role.Contains("Admin")`

Comment: So, you want to repeat this code (even after you fix the problem talked by @devNull) in every controller and method of your application? Did you consider to use an Authorize attribute? Did you consider to use the ASP.NET Identity library? There are so many things to consider in Authorization and Authentication. An example from your code above handled by Identity is the _clear text passwords_ problem.

Comment: Thank you @devNull it worked! 
Steve, yes i know the clear text passwords is a problem. Any suggestion in what step I should take?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity but you should look at the exact version for your technology stack.